# Trying to showing image asynchronously with laravel asset() helper in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to get the img file name with fetch from database and call it with asset helper.

I can successfully fetch the img file name from database, but can't show the img.

```
async function getIcons(test){
  let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
  let test_icons = test;
  console.log(test_icons);
  fetch('poseicon/req',{
    headers: {
      "Accept-Charset": "utf-8",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "Accept": "application/json, text-plain, */*",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true  
      },
    method: 'get',
    credentials: "same-origin"
  }).then(icon => icon.json()).then(icon =>{
      let data;
      data = icon.filter(x => x.name === test_icons);
      let path = '/img/'+data[0].icons;
      document.getElementById("icons").innerHTML = `<img src="{{asset('${path}')}}" width="200" height="200">`;//like this

  })
```

in console
[image]

Note: I'm not using storage:link, accessing `public/img` folder directly.

if you have any solution for this please share.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access blade functions in a javascript promise, which shouldn't be available after the initial page render, I would suggest you create a front end helper function to get the asset url and then just use that function from javascript

```
const getAssetUrl(image) => `your path to assets/${image}`
```

---

but since you are in Laravel I assume you've created a model for Icons from what I see in icon request. I would suggest you use a foreach loop to show the icons there instead that would be something like

```
@foreach(App\Icon::all() as $icon)
   <img src="{{asset($icon->path)}}" width="200" height="200">`
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, if you don't mind please tell me more about front end helper function?

Comment: create a function on javascript that would resolve the image path when an image is given,  check the function I've written above getAssetUrl that will return the path of each image